# Python Celery task.delay() when broker Queue is full

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I am using `celery 4` with `RabbitMQ` as broker. I have limited `Queue` (size == 200). My main code looks like:

```
for i in range(200):
    tasks.delay(i)
```

It works if range of i <= size. If I call something like this:

```
for i in range(2000):
    tasks.delay(i)
```

And size limit is 200, the `Queue` will be full and rest of the task will be skipped.

Can anyone please explain how to handle this situation? I need to wait till `Queue` will be free and `insert` another task.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a RabbitMQ behavior. [RabbitMQ docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html).

> Messages will be dropped or dead-lettered from the front of the queue to make room for new messages once the limit is reached.

You can either manage this in RabbitMQ by modifying the config or you can use multiple queues. 
Another way to fix this would be to use [celery's apply_async](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) which can let you set a retry value, eta or retry_policy. BTW, delay() is just a shortcut to apply_async().

Comment: Perfect thanks, if i use redis will i have same problem? I just expect, that delay will wait till queue will be free.

Comment: I think with Redis is a little different. Since Redis is just a key/value database it does not really have the concept of a queue as RabbitMQ. This means that there is not a queue limit in Redis but you do have a limit in Reids which is how much memory and/or disk space you allocate for Redis.

This is why Celery is very good at scaling it so you can add more workers if needed. Hope this helps

Comment: @wilima, btw. If the answer did help you out. Could you mark it as the correct answer? Thanks.